# Как добавить в заголовок данные используя URL (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно в Codeigniter3 добавить в заголовок статьи какие либо данные.

Вывод заголовка статьи идет таким образом:

```
<title><?=$page_title?></title>
```

Например на сайте есть 2 страницы:

1) *site.ru/article.html*

2) *site.ru/article-2.html*

Я хочу к странице article-2.html добавить к заголовку текущий год используя:

```
<?php echo date('Y') ?>
```

т.е. чтобы в статье - article.html заголовок остался такой как был, а по адресу article-2.html к заголовку добавилась информация (например год)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен.
В контроллере после вывода заголовка:

```
$this->data['page_title']   = $post['title'];
```

Вставить следующее:

```
if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'category/article-555.html'){ 
    $this->data['page_title']   = $post['title'] .date('Y');
}
```

Где category/article-555.html - это нужная страница для которой нужно добавить в конце заголовка какое либо содержимое

Comment: так тоже можно, а если будет много таких страниц? запаришься каждую вписывать сюда)

Comment: На данный момент получилось только так решить. Ваш вариант неподходит, т.к. он добавляет год во все заголовки, а мне нужно применить только к определенным статьям

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере добавляй что хочешь в title. И передавай массив data[] в вид.

```
    $data['title']="Название сайта ".date('Y'); //к примеру для одной страницы
    $this->load->view('view',$data);
```

А во всех видах

```
<title><?=$title?></title>
```

Comment: Да, но так у меня изменятся заголовки всех статей, т.к. используйте один вид ля вывода. Можно ли как-то по URL добавить?

Comment: Почему в одной статье должен выводиться год, а в другой нет? Какой критерий?

Comment: У меня в контроллере есть `$this->data['page_title'] = $post['title'];
  $this->load->view('view', $this->data);` А в выводе используется  `<title><?=$page_title?></title>` т.е. вывод заголовков из БД для всех статей. Как дописать что-либо в заголовок используя URL или ID статьи, т.е. дописать к статье год, но только к одной

Comment: http_://example.com/номер_статьи?year=2016 и берешь из массива GET переменную year, если такая есть